# Enable JavaScript in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

How do I enable JavaScript in a Windows Phone HTML5 app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After creating a new WP8 HTML5 project, open up MainPage.xaml and set `IsScriptEnabled="True"` to the `<WebBrowser />` control.

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser"
                  IsScriptEnabled="True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Loaded="Browser_Loaded"
                  NavigationFailed="Browser_NavigationFailed" />
```

Remember: with great power comes great responsibility.